# Jquery: .on('input') not firing when input value changed by another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Here's the code:

```
$("input[type='text']").on('input', function() { ...stuff here... });  //first function

$('input[type="text"]').click(function() {  //second function
  $('#keyboard').show();
  $('#keyboard .letter').click(function() {
    var currentValue = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    alert(currentValue);
    $('input[type="text"]').val( currentValue + $(this).text() );
  });
});
```

The short version is, when I type in this text input, the top function fires. In the second function, I make a keyboard appear, and change the value of the input based on user clicks. However, the first function is not firing when the input value is changed by means of the second function. Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$("input[type='text']").trigger('input');
```

Put that in your second function.
Merely setting the value of a textbox using javascript will not trigger the input event, thus your input event handler will not fire. In this scenario, you need to trigger that event handler manually.

> Note: You should *not* be using the input event handler. See this link and look at the the awful browser compatibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.oninput . You will probably be better served by the change event instead.

Comment: Agreed. this should invoke the change event not input.

Comment: I didn't even know there *was* an `oninput` event!

Comment: I am making packaged app for Chrome, so I only care about webkit. `.on('input')` works there. Although I did change that to `.change()` and it would not work. No idea why. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Changing the value of an input element using JavaScript, using `.val()` for example, won't fire the `.change()` event. Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: It does fire the event in IE 10 and 11.  But not edge.  (not sure on older versions).